# Passing a file from WCF to WCF

Tags: vb.net, wcf, io, system

I have a pdf on one server I need to pass on another server. Both have WCF's published to them.

On the 'serving' server, I have the following code (thanks antisanity!):

Function GetPDF(ByVal fileName as String) as FileStream

```
Return File.OpenRead(fileName);
```

End Function

But I have no idea how to actually write the file on my 'receiving' server. I've been playing with System.IO, but I'm not having much luck. I need something like:

Sub WritePDF()

System.IO.WriteFile(MyService.GetPDF("Test.pdf"), "C:\NewPDF.pdf")

End Sub

Any ideas on this would be greatly apprecaited!

Thanks,
Jason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is what you're looking for:

.Net 4:

```
Using fileStream As Stream = File.Create("C:\NewPDF.pdf")
    MyService.GetPDF("Test.pdf").CopyTo(fileStream)
End Using
```

.Net 2.0/3.5:

```
    Using fileStream As Stream = File.Create("C:\NewPDF.pdf")
        Using inputStream As Stream = MyService.GetPDF("Test.pdf")
            Dim buffer(1023) As Byte
            Dim count As Integer = buffer.Length

            Do
                count = inputStream.Read(buffer, 0, count)
                If count = 0 Then Exit Do
                fileStream.Write(buffer, 0, count)
            Loop
        End Using
    End Using
```

Comment: Tried it, but got the "CopyTo is not a member of System.IO.FileStream

Comment: This method was only added in .Net 4. Are you on 2 or 3.5?

Comment: OK, added the pre-.Net 4 version. It's just getting a bit uglier in that case.

Comment: Sorry, this one's a stickler. It 'almost' works, but now I'm gettting a 'NullReferenceException was unhandled' on Count = inputStream.Read(buffer, 0, Count).

Comment: At that line it can only refer to `inputStream`. Did you debug this? Is there actually `null/Nothing` coming back from the service? Also, just to clarify, in the above code, `MyService` is supposed to be an _instance_ of your service proxy. Is that the case in your code?

Comment: Yeah, was just going to note that I have a problem in the host. It's not returning anything. Tried calling a regular VB function with that logic and it worked great. Thanks so much for your help!